# Play2.5 scala slick configuration for mariadb

Tags: scala, playframework, mariadb, slick

I'm trying to setup a play2.5 app with slick but i'm getting an error on app startup,  any clue how to fix it?

I have created the project from Play Scala Seed activator and I'm trying to add slick to the project, but for now unsuccessfully

The error :

```
! @72ef93323 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[AbstractMethodError: play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion$$anon$1.copy$default$11()Lscala/Option;]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:269)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:195)
    at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:46)
    at play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:66)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:46)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.handle(PlayRequestHandler.scala:81)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.channelRead(PlayRequestHandler.scala:162)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: play.core.server.netty.NettyModelConversion$$anon$1.copy$default$11()Lscala/Option;
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$.taggedRequest(HandlerInvoker.scala:86)
    at play.core.routing.TaggingInvoker$$anon$2.tagRequest(HandlerInvoker.scala:45)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$$anonfun$4.apply(HttpRequestHandler.scala:119)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$$anonfun$4.apply(HttpRequestHandler.scala:118)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler.handlerForRequest(HttpRequestHandler.scala:118)
    at play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:56)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:46)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.handle(PlayRequestHandler.scala:81)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.channelRead(PlayRequestHandler.scala:162)
```

the build.sbt

```
name := "play-scala"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.0-RC1" % Test,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "2.0.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "2.0.0",
  "org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client" % "1.5.5",
  cache,
  ws
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

The application.conf

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=******
slick.dbs.default.db.password="*******"
```

Comment: This error may indicates you have two incompatible version of netty dependency in project

Comment: hmm if I remove the play-slick from the sbt build this error goes away, could be that the play-slick version is wrong?

Comment: Inspecting the dependency tree of project may helps